# How to get this window with GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, gdm

[image: GDM Theme customizer]

How can i get this window in Ubuntu 11.04 with **GNOME 3**?

Answer (score 1):

... Not.
That *window* was taken out in Ubuntu... I think it was 8.10? So it wouldn't be included in Ubuntu 11.04 either.
It was replaced by a simple login screen configuration tool with only a few options.

Comment: Well, why would you keep above configuration window when GDM simply could not be configured like that anymore?

Comment: The old GDM had so many problems and bugs, that Ubuntu decided to make one of their own. It wasn't as configurable, but it was at least stable. Btw, there are ways to change  the wallpaper and icons of the new GDM.

Comment: Yes, but it's quite hacky in my opinion. Or maybe they improved it. I haven't used Ubuntu for some time, but my knowledge is still pretty extensive :)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick easy change use Ubuntu Tweak (Google search)

Then go to Startup - Login Settings
Unlock with you password and then you can change the logo and background.